# adding custom images to matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a plot with two custom images below the plot, but I haven't figured out how to do it. 
I'm using python 3.7 and matplotlib

this is what I have so far

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'some data':[2,0,0,3,2,1,4],
    'other data':[5,1,0,5,2,2,3]
})
logo = plt.imread('A.jpg')
title = 'images'
ax = df.plot(kind='bar',x='some data',y='other data')
ax.set_title(title, fontsize=20)
ax.figure.figimage(logo, 40, 40, alpha=.15, zorder=1)
```

This is the result

[image: result]

and this is what I'm trying to get.

[image: expected]

[This is the image in the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOYHq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the images how you have them displayed in your expected output (one aligned left, one aligned right, both below plot) you can do something like this

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'some data':[2,0,0,3,2,1,4],
    'other data':[5,1,0,5,2,2,3]
})
logo = plt.imread('A.jpg')
title = 'images'
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
df.plot(kind='bar',x='some data',y='other data', ax=ax)
ax.set_title(title, fontsize=20)
h = logo.shape[1]/fig.bbox.ymax
fig.subplots_adjust(0.05, h, 0.97, 0.93)
ax.figure.figimage(logo, 0, 0, alpha=.15, zorder=1)
ax.figure.figimage(logo, fig.bbox.xmax - logo.shape[0], 0, alpha=.15, zorder=1)
plt.show()
```

This will resize the figure to accommodate the height of the logos: `logo.shape[0]` is the width of the logo in pixels `logo.shape[1]` is the height of the logo in pixels, `fig.bbox.ymax` is the height of the figure in pixels. `h` is the fractional height of the logo which can then be used in `fig.subplots_adjust` to adjust the height accordingly.

It then positions one `logo` with the bottom left corner at offset `(0, 0)` and another with the bottom left corner at `(fig.bbox.xmax - logo.shape[0], 0)` where `fig.bbox.xmax` is the width of the figure in pixels.<sup>[1](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html)</sup>

This will give you something that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm trying what you said but now the logo doesn't appear

Comment: @Akarii If you post a [mcve] I can tell you why it isn't showing up

Comment: The only item that is missing is the image, I can load it

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm trying to replicate the code, but the logo and the plot are overlapping

Comment: @Akarii You can’t use `tight_layout` with this, if you aren’t but it still go ahead and add your current code to the question and I will take a look

Comment: @Akarii How are you running the code and what versions of matplotlib and python are you using?

Comment: I'm running the code with jupyter, from anaconda, my python version is 3.7.5 and matplotlib 3.1.1

Comment: @Akarii And you are running my exact code as above?

Comment: Yes, but I just realized something, I was visualizing the plot in Jupyter notebook, once I save the plot its ok, except by the size of the graph in comparison with the logos everything is ok, thanks for the help. I'll fix the problen with the size maybe by resampling the logos

Comment: @Akarii I'm glad it works for you, be sure to mark the answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so the question is marked accordingly for future users.

Answer (score -1):

you can export the plot as a svg file. Open this with inkscape and add the picture.

Comment: I'm talking about exporting, not importing. I use matplotlib 3.1.1. that works. in the documentation it also says: `The file format, e.g. 'png', 'pdf', 'svg', ...` https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html

Comment: My mistake, I retract the comment